# "too many variables specified" error when using global macro

Tags: stata

I have the following Stata code. Note that `lowess` is a locally weighted regression of *yvar* on *xvar*, a form of kernel smoothing.

```
qui tab vy, gen(vy_) // dummy for village-year (8 total)
qui tab soiltype, gen(soiltype_) //dummy for soil type (3 types)
qui tab topo, gen(topo_) //dummy for topological type (4 types)

global controls2 soiltype_* topo_* vy_*

foreach var of global controls2 {
lowess `var' lnha, nograph gen(yhat_`var')
gen res_`var'=`var'-yhat_`var'
drop yhat_`var'
}
```

In the `foreach` loop, Stata returns an error: too many variables specified. Per previous questions posted on this topic, my first thought was that I had a variable name with a space in it in the lowess command using `var` (i.e., the elements of `controls2`). But I don't (you can see all elements of this global in the code above). Any other ideas for why Stata returns that error?

Answer (score 3):

Two previous answers both give good advice, but neither fully explains the point at issue.

First, my suggested code (incidentally, "topological" is probably a solecism here for "topographical"):

```
qui tab vy, gen(vy_) // dummy for village-year (8 total)
qui tab soiltype, gen(soiltype_) // dummy for soil type (3 types)
qui tab topo, gen(topo_) // dummy for topological type (4 types)

foreach var of varlist soiltype_* topo_* vy_* { 
    lowess `var' lnha, nograph gen(yhat_`var')
    gen res_`var' = `var' - yhat_`var'
    drop yhat_`var'
}
```

Now an explanation:

- Putting `soiltype_* topo_* vy_*` in a global macro and then referring `foreach` to that global macro hands `foreach` a list with precisely three items, namely `soiltype_* topo_* vy_*`. `foreach` tries to pass each item in turn to `lowess` but that fails first time round as `lowess` will not accept `lowess soiltype* lnha` as syntax, hence your error message. (Note also that `yhat_soiltype*` would also not be acceptable as an argument for `gen()`.)
- Using a local rather than global macro would pose exactly the same problem and that is not a solution here. The arguments for using local rather than global macros are irrelevant to that point.
- You need to spell out to `foreach` that variable lists need to be expanded, which is why `varlist` not `global` is the syntax required.
- You put varlists in a global only to take them out immediately afterwards. That does no harm but can be avoided by using the varlists directly. This is a matter of taste or style.

Comment: Great explanation. And yes, I meant topographical (the vbl label is actually "toposequence" and I wasn't thinking clearly about what the "topo" was short for).

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to your macro incorrectly.

```
...
foreach var of varlist $controls2 {
...
```

And it may help to specify the macro as:

```
global controls2 "soiltype_* topo_* vy_*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the approach that works:

```
sysuse auto
qui tab rep78, gen(rep_) // dummy for rep78 (5 total)
qui tab foreign, gen(foreign_) //dummy for foreign (2 types)

local k rep_* foreign_*
foreach var of varlist `k'{
lowess `var' mpg, nograph gen(yhat_`var')
gen res_`var'=`var'-yhat_`var'
drop yhat_`var'
}
```

For your example (not tested)

```
qui tab vy, gen(vy_) // dummy for village-year (8 total)
qui tab soiltype, gen(soiltype_) //dummy for soil type (3 types)
qui tab topo, gen(topo_) //dummy for topological type (4 types)

local k vy_* soiltype_* top_*
foreach var of `k'{
lowess `var' lnha, nograph gen(yhat_`var')
gen res_`var'=`var'-yhat_`var'
drop yhat_`var'
}
```

Note: Try using local ; global is usually not recommended